# Is there any difference between inverse beta decay and beta-plus decay? If so, what is it?

Tags: radiation, radioactivity

In the textbook, we have beta-plus decay as:   p --> n + e + Ve

But, in the book "In search of the edge of time", as the author explains the birth of Neutron stars, the highly energetic, degenerate electrons due to the immense gravitational pressure/density smash/penetrate into protons to create neutrons. It is termed 'inverse beta decay'.

But, the 'inverse beta decay' somehow looked similar to the 'beta-plus decay'. Are they both the same or different? Please explain thoroughly if you can. Thanks!

Comment: I think the "electron capture" reaction is often referred to as inverse beta decay in neutron star physics.

Answer (score 2):

IBD is [something completely different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_beta_decay), $\bar{\nu}_e+p\to e^+ + n$. This is closely related to electron capture, $e^- + p\to\nu_e + n$.

Comment: I already read the Wikipedia page. It didn't help that much, certainly because of my little knowledge on the subject. Please, explain/elaborate if you can. Thanks.

Comment: This. Interestingly the process called "inverse beta decay" is neither a decay in and of itself nor the reverse of beta decay. It is a charged current weak scattering event.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more?